# Tumblr API: Loop through all existing posts and add text

Tags: php, ruby, tumblr

I need to loop through all of my existing posts on my Tumblr and add text to each (a URL) but the Tumblr mass editor only allows to add tags in mass.

How can I use the API to do what I need to do (there doesn't seem to be examples of using the API in this way to edit)?

PHP or Ruby is fine.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. The API doesn't provide a way to edit all posts at once. You have to do that one at a time.

You can retrieve a list of your posts via the [posts method](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts) `api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{blog-identifier}/posts?api_key={key}`, which will return up to 20 posts at a time. You can specify an `offset` parameter, to continue pulling in more posts until you reach the end.

```
$requestURI = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/$blogId/posts?api_key=$APIkey&offset=%d";
if ($response = file_get_contents(sprintf($requestURI, 0))) {
    $data = json_decode($response);
    $posts = $data["response"]["posts"];
    $totalPosts = $data['total_posts'];
    $gotPosts = count($posts);
    while($gotPosts < $totalPosts) {
        $offset = $totalPosts - $gotPosts;
        $response = file_get_contents(sprintf($requestURI, $offset));
        $data = json_decode($response);
        $posts = array_merge($posts, $data["response"]["posts"]);
        $gotPosts = count($posts);
    }
}
```

Once you have accumulated a list of all your posts for a given Tumblelog you can then iterate over them and edit each via the [edit method](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#editing) `api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{blog-identifier}/post/edit`.

```
foreach($posts as $post) {
    /* do your edit posts here */
}
```

Comment: How do I add URL to post body though?

Comment: Read the API documentation linked in the answer. You already have the post body, just concatenate the link you want there and resend the post.